# How to insert additional title before address in address bar in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

When visiting some web sites I noticed that some developers insert additional title or description in the address bar right before URL separated with | symbol.

The good example: [WELLS FARGO home page](https://www.wellsfargo.com):

[image: image of address bar: Wells Fargo & Company [US] | https: //www.wellsfargo.com]

Here I am trying to figure out how developers inserted "Wells Fargo & Company [US]" before "https://www.wellsfargo.com"

I have been opening an 'View page source' page and tried finding it there (html tag, meta tag, script or source to code) but could not find anything. I am using last version of Chrome.

Comment: That is the SSL cert: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114007/how-do-i-show-the-company-name-in-the-browser-address-bar-next-to-the-ssl-padloc

Comment: Chrome and FF are removing this "feature" in their next versions: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/chrome-and-firefox-changes-spark-the-end-of-ev-certificates/